# Oracle Access Manager Header Lost during Posts

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oim, oam

We have an ASP.net/C# 4.0 forms app and moved it to a Windows 2008r2 server and upgraded Oracle Access Manager from 10g to 11g and are now losing the headers passed by OAM during posts. We're checking the headers in the global.asax Application_PostAuthenticateRequest method. It had worked on Windows 2003 and OAM10g, but now whenever we do a post (either to another page or a postback) one of the requests that passes through the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest method is void of the OAM headers.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a setting either in OAM or Windows/IIS that could explain the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never found an answer to this, I don't think we ever got the right people at oracle involved to understand the issue. We ended up just grabbing the OAM headers at the master page initialization and storing them in session variables to get around this issue.